# Simple Connection to Database in Java EE

Tags: java, oracle, jakarta-ee, jpa

I'm new to Java EE; I have a good background in ASP .NET with WebForms and MVC. I find that nothing is as easy in Java EE as it is in ASP .NET. Nevertheless, all I am trying to do is connect to a local Oracle Express database using persistance on a JBoss runtime. I am absolutely going mad trying to get this to work. In ASP .NET, all I had to do was specify a connection string and walla. I would really appreciate it if someone could either show me what I'm doing wrong or point me to a good resource to use JPA in eclipse.

Here's my code:

> persistence.xml

I am sure that the database properties are correct; eclipse was able to make a successful ping.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="Testing" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
        <class>model.Testq</class>
        <properties>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="system"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="admin"/>
            <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.driver" value="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"/>
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

> Testq class

This class is just a simple entity in java for a very simple table in the oracle database.

```
package model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@NamedQuery(name="Testq.findAll", query="SELECT t FROM Testq t")
public class Testq implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @Column(name="T_ID")
    private long tId;

    private String descr;

    public Testq() {
        tId = 0;
        descr = "ONE";
    }

    public long getTId() {
        return this.tId;
    }

    public void setTId(long tId) {
        this.tId = tId;
    }

    public String getDescr() {
        return this.descr;
    }

    public void setDescr(String descr) {
        this.descr = descr;
    }

}
```

> DB Servlet

I am using this to display the result of a query from the database, **but it fails at line 28.**

```
package com.db;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;
import javax.persistence.EntityManagerFactory;
import javax.persistence.Persistence;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import model.Testq;

@WebServlet("/DB")
public class DB extends HttpServlet {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public DB() {
        super();
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    protected void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        Testq test = new Testq();
        EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("Testing");
        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
        test = em.createNamedQuery("Testq.findAll", Testq.class).getSingleResult();
        em.close();
        emf.close();
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println(test.getDescr());
    }
}
```

Comment: "It fails..." ... *How* does it fail?

Comment: I'll open a port for you to look at the error. Now its actually on line 37, which is not a line in the DB.class

Comment: Well a stacktrace would be much more helpful. Are you really supposed to instantiate the Entitymanager yourself? I would let them be injected.
And what line should be line 37 ??

Comment: Here is a link to the error: http://conntechsolutions.com/ERRORS/ERROR.html

Comment: And the thing is that the line the the error is occurring on is not in the DB class. There are only 36 lines, but the error is on 37

Comment: You need to include the oracle driver jar in your deployment.

Comment: I included it in the WEB-INF

Comment: `javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-4003] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException Exception Description: Configuration error. Class [oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver] not found.
`

Comment: Maybe I included the wrong jar. I'll check it.

Comment: If you look in this screenshot, you will see in the WEB-INF, I am using the same driver used by eclipse to connect to the DB: http://conntechsolutions.com/ERRORS/screen.png

I am able to ping the database successfully with that same driver: http://conntechsolutions.com/ERRORS/ping.png

Comment: It's not on the classpath when you're running the code. It needs to be in WEB-INF/lib.

Comment: I just added the driver to the libraries through the project properties, but the error is still occurring. Also in the bottom marker pane, I noticed that JPA has no connection to the database. How would I set this up? http://conntechsolutions.com/ERRORS/classpath.png

Comment: Hey `Dave Newton`, I just read this again and noticed that your answer was correct. If you post your answer, I will give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you all so much. it turns out that the driver had to be in the lib folder of WEB-INF. I really appreciate all of your help, specifically Thorbjørn Ravn Andersen for identifying the error when I was sick of dealing with it.